# how to pass the variable from included template to the template where it is included?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In Django Views:-

```
if request.is_ajax():
    t = get_template('bar-templates.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'edit': True, 'user':'some-user' }))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

There is two templates:
Main template `(foo-templates.html)` which includes the  template `(bar-templates.html)`. In context `edit` and `user` is passed to the `bar-templates.html` But this variable is also used in `foo-templates.html`. In django we used to `{{ edit }}` to catch the variable. Since this variable comes in `bar-templates.html`. How can I use this to `foo-templates.html`.

**foo-templates.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<div class="container">
{{ edit }} // Here I am not getting the edit value
    {% if edit %} // I need this edit value. But this value is in context with `bar-templates.html`
     do something 
    {% else %}
     do something
    {% endif %}
    <div class="content">
       {% include "bar-templates.html" %}
    </div>
```

**bar-templaes.html**

{{ edit }} // Here It gives me the edit value
    This is the templates which I am sending from views.

How to use the `included template` variable values to the template where it get included.

Answer (score 1):

Using details from your other post, which you should edit to include into this one:

From what i can tell, you are trying to add a "selected" class to your sidebar menu. This won't work for you because as gcbirzan said, you aren't going to be able to get the context of your ajax response into your base template. On top of that you aren't going to re-render the base template so it wouldn't be changing anyways.

Using javascript you can extract the foo_id from your `part.html`. Since that code isn't shown, lets say you have your foo_id in a hidden div, `<div id="foo_id" style="display:none;">foo_2</div>`

Now you can change your ajax function to something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    cache: 'false',
    url:"/foobar/",
    success:function(data) {
        $('#main-content').html(data);
        var $foo_id = $('#foo_id').val();
        $('#foo1>ul>li.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $('#'+ foo_id).addClass('selected');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply render foo:

```
t = get_template('foo-templates.html')
html = t.render(Context({'edit': True, 'user':'some-user' }))
```

then 'foo' and the included 'bar' both have the same value for 'edit'.

I don't completely understand your question, but have I answered it?