# Including a template does not render the variable value

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to pass the variable from included template to the template where it is included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541312/how-to-pass-the-variable-from-included-template-to-the-template-where-it-is-inclu)

**main.html**

```
{% extends "new-base.html" %}
{% block side-bar %}
<div id="foo1">
     {% for foo in foo_list %}
     {{ foo_id }} // ???
         {% ifequal foo.id foo_id %}
          <li id="my-id_{{ foo.id }}" class="select"><a href="#.">
         {% else %}
          <li id="my-id_{{ foo.id }}" class="no-select"><a href="#.">
         {% endifequal %}
      {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endblock side-bar %}

{% block content %}
<div class="content" id="main-content">
 {% include "template/part.html" %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**part.html**

This html is get included in the `main.html`

**views.py**

```
if request.is_ajax():
    t = get_template('part.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'foo_id': foo_id}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

In response it will send the `part.html` But I am using `foo_id` it into `main.html`. `main.html` 
included the `part.html` But `{{ foo_id }}` in `main.html` is not giving me any value. I indicated the position by `???` But when I render whole template (not adding the html
data in the div ) then it gives the proper data.

**jquery**

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    cache: 'false',
    url:"/foobar/",
    success:function(data) {
        $('#main-content').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: exact duplicate of an unanswered question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541312/how-to-pass-the-variable-from-included-template-to-the-template-where-it-is-inclu

Comment: sorry for that but I need to formulate the question more accurately

Comment: You can edit your question to make it more clear instead of creating a new account and re-posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question. I assume you mean that you want foo_id to be accessible from the AJAX request response, but that's not possible, since the page is rendered (and the context set) before the AJAX request is made, so part.html is just a template to django, and it uses the context of the main template to render the whole page. You need to manually change foo_id based on the response, in JavaScript, or fix your views (call the same function from the ajax view and the main view to get foo_id)

What confused me about your question is:

> But when I render whole template (not adding the html data in the div ) then it gives the proper data.

, which I read as foo_id being set if you don't include part.html, so sorry if that's the case (even though it doesn't make sense to me...).